# How do I define a SQLAlchemy function and use it as default for a table field?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/defaults.html#triggered-columns) has this example:

```
t = Table('test', meta,
        Column('abc', MyType, default=func.generate_new_value(), primary_key=True)
)
```

> Where above, when Table.insert() is used, the func.generate_new_value() expression will be pre-executed in the context of a scalar SELECT statement, and the new value will be applied to the subsequent INSERT, while at the same time being made available to the ResultProxy.inserted_primary_key attribute.

However it doesn't say how this `func.generate_new_value()` is defined.

I need to define a function that will select the max `abc` element (not a primary key in my case) from all `test` rows, then increment it by 1, and then pass this value to SQLAlchemy which hopefully can then INSERT it in the new row.

Answer (score 1):

func.ANYTHING() is actually calling an SQL function from your database. 'ANYTHING' is the name of that function. So you will have to define your function directly on your database as an SQL function.

See also:
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=func#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func